# The predicted result error is much larger than the training error with the same training set?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I trained a CNN model for Medical Image Segmentation.
I ran 150 epochs, finally showed that 92% using dice_coef, which seemed to be good. But when it comes to real predicting, it is found that less than 1% using dice_coef. In order to check if it is over-fitting, I used the same training set to make predictions, and the results are still very poor. The model does not work at all. But I don't understand why the train loss is very good. code show as below.

```
    # Metric function
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

# Loss funtion
def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)

def get_unet(IMG_WIDTH=256,IMG_HEIGHT=256,IMG_CHANNELS=1):
    inputs = Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
    s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 1) (inputs)
    c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (inputs)
    c1 = Dropout(0.1) (c1)
    c1 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c1)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)
    c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p1)
    c2 = Dropout(0.1) (c2)
    c2 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c2)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)

    c3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p2)
    c3 = Dropout(0.2) (c3)
    c3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c3)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c3)

    c4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p3)
    c4 = Dropout(0.2) (c4)
    c4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c4)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (c4)

    c5 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (p4)
    c5 = Dropout(0.3) (c5)
    c5 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c5)

    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    c6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u6)
    c6 = Dropout(0.2) (c6)
    c6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c6)

    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    c7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u7)
    c7 = Dropout(0.2) (c7)
    c7 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c7)

    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    c8 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u8)
    c8 = Dropout(0.1) (c8)
    c8 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c8)

    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
    c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (u9)
    c9 = Dropout(0.1) (c9)
    c9 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='elu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same') (c9)

    outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[dice_coef])
    return model

u_net = get_unet()
u_net.fit(train_set,train_traget,batch_size=16,epochs=150)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btF9A.png)

```
train_pre = u_net.predict(train_set,verbose=1)
sess = tf.Session()
print (sess.run(np.sum(dice_coef(1.0*train_traget[i].reshape((256,256)), np.float64(train_pre[i].reshape((256,256)))))))
```

0.005191509794539865

there is the prediction and real images:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6G2d.png) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFJrI.png)

Comment: Thanks for all the help